# Why aren't <li> indented next to <img> float:left?

Tags: html, css

When I put a `<ul>` next to a float:left image, the bullets overlap the image, and the whole `<ul>` isn't indented from the left margin as expected.

How do I fix this?

In the example below, compare the position of the bullets and text in the first `<ul>` (text lines up under "e" in "camera") to the second `<ul>` (text ends up under the "A"):

```html
<p>A camera has:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Lens</li>
  <li>Box</li>
  <li>Sensor</li>
</ul>

<img style="float:left" src="http://nerdfever.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/imgres.jpg" alt="Camera" />

<p>A camera has:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Lens</li>
  <li>Box</li>
  <li>Sensor</li>
</ul>
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to contain the overflow. You can add `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto`

```css
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>A camera has:</p>

<ul>
   <li>Lens</li>
   <li>Box</li>
   <li>Sensor</li>
</ul>

<img style="float:left" src="http://nerdfever.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/imgres.jpg" alt="Camera" />

<p>A camera has:</p>

<ul>
   <li>Lens</li>
   <li>Box</li>
   <li>Sensor</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the list-style-position:

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<p>A camera has:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Lens</li>
  <li>Box</li>
  <li>Sensor</li>
</ul>

<img style="float:left" src="http://nerdfever.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/imgres.jpg" alt="Camera" />

<p>A camera has:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Lens</li>
  <li>Box</li>
  <li>Sensor</li>
</ul>
```